# vim Comment Newlines Unexpected Behavior

Tags: newline, vim

In using vim, when I start a comment with //, immediately after I type a space, it begins a new comment line.

For instance, if I typed the following:

```
//hello world my name is stefan
```

I would get:

```
//hello
//world
//my
//name
//is
//stefan
```

This behavior has manifested itself in python code as well, where if I begin a line with print, each space is interpreted as a newline

```
print "Hello world my name is Stefan"
```

Is

```
print
"hello
world
my
name
is
stefan"
```

Is this the intended behavior or do I have a setting messed up? The following is my .vimrc:

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <email address>
" Last change:  2006 Nov 16
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" TagList plugin settings
nmap <f12> :TlistToggle<end>

" Use Vim settings, rather then Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

set nobackup        " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
" set mouse=a

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

set   backupdir=./.backup,.,/tmp
set   directory=.,./.backup,/tmp

map <F1> :NERDTree <CR>
map <F2> :q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>:q!<CR>
map <F5> :AV<CR>
map <F6> :AS<CR>
map <F7> :IHV<CR>
map <F8> :IHS<CR>
```

Comment: May I suggest mapping <F2> to :qa! instead? :)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this, but I suggest that you do a :set and put the output here, so that we can see what settings are active.

Comment: @roe lol, this is my accumulated vim knowledge, I wanted to leave that in for posterity ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you mixed up "tw" (aka textwidth) and the old vi command to set the text margin "wm".  "tw" sets the actual width of the page (ie. tw=77 means you want 77 letters per line) but "wm" set the how far from the edge of the screen to wrap, so on an 80 column screen "wm=3" would have the same effect as "tw=77".  So if your tw is set to something very small, it would try to wrap after every word.

Comment: I'd just like to add that I did it again and came back here to fix it. You've helped me twice Paul! :)

Comment: @Stefan, yesterday I needed to find how to do a particular SQL query, so I searched on SO and found a question that I'd asked a year ago when I was working at a different job, and the answer that I'd accepted back then helped me again.  Almost makes you wish you could vote it up again, doesn't it?  Well, you don't have to - the answer is there to help anybody who needs it, even if it's you again.

Comment: Haha, my thought exactly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't spot it in your vimrc, but it appears your tw is set to something low (other than 0), like 5 or so. Try setting tw=0, and see what happens.

**EDIT:**
As Paul pointed out you might have mixed up tw (textwidth) and ts (tabstop) which is commonly set to 4 or 2.